# how to handle multiple views within a single view with backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone and I don't fully understand it yet, and I've come across a situation I can't find any documentation on. What I if I have a view that contains multiple views? For example, I have a view called `StackView`. The purpose of this view is to neatly lay out a set of cards. It manages the animation of adding, removing, and adjusting cards in the stack. Each card is a `CardView`. How would I handle this? I've seen people talk about views within views by simple creating a variable in the view and assigning the View instance to that variable. Should I just be adding an array of `CardView`s in a variable of a `StackView`?

Answer (score 1):

That's what I do, and it works well. Here's a snippet of a View I use in an application. I've re-written it back into regular javascript from my coffeescript, so I apologize for any typos:

```
render: function() {
  var _this = this;
  this.$el.html(this.template());

  this.listItemViews = [];

  // for each model in the collection, create a new sub-view and add
  // it to the parent view
  this.collection.each(function(model){
    var view = new App.Views.Projects.ListItem({model:model}); // create the new sub-view
    _this.listItemViews.push(view); // add it to the array
    _this.$('#project-table tbody').append(view.render().$el); // append its rendered element to the parent view's DOM
  });
  return this;
}
```

This lets my Table view maintain a reference to all the `listItemView` views.

Of course, if you do this, you should make sure to properly remove these child views and unbind any events when you remove the parent view.

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) don't use `var self`, use something else (such as `_this`) or the `context` argument to [`_.each`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each), [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self) is always around so `self` can cause confusion (yes, I learned this the hard way); (2) collections have some [Underscore methods mixed in](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so `this.collection.each(function(model) { ... })` works.

Comment: thanks; good stuff. i'll update my code (and this answer) accordingly

Comment: wait a sec. so I have an array of views. I rendered them on the page. my parent class `Stack` needs to be able to call a function on a subview when that subview's element is clicked. How can I do that? Here's the scenerio: The `CardView` class has a function called `showActionMode()`. That function only will work when actionModeEnabled is true. It is false until you click on it in the stack, in which case the stack should place a focus border on the element and call they view's enableActionMode.

Comment: @LordZardeck, well, you could bind an event handler to the sub-view before pushing it to the array: `view.bind('click a.someLink',function(){ this.doSomething});`. That would trigger the `doSomething` function of the parent view when someone clicks the anchor with `someLink` class contained within the subview. At least, I think so; can't test it. However, if the function to be called on the event is also contained within the sub-view, there's no need to involve the parent view at all; the sub-view should manage its own events when possible.

Comment: When possible is the key. The problem is, there can be many different kinds of stacks, each one handling activating ActionMode differently